# Test Class Problem

Tags: trigger, unit-test, class

I am having a hard time to run my test class for my trigger WHERE my trigger updates the Contacts Mailing to Accounts Biliing Address whenever the Accounts Billing Address is updated.
This is my Trigger

```
trigger UpdateContactBillingAddress on Account (after update) {

 Set accountId = new Set();
List contactsToUpdate = new List();

for(Account acc: Trigger.new){

// Please perform a check to see if address was updated

accountId.add(acc.Id); //accounts that were updated.
}

for(Contact c : [Select Id, MailingCity, MailingStreet, MailingCountry,
Account.BillingCity, Account.BillingStreet, Account.BillingCountry
from Contact where Account.Id in: accountId]){

c.MailingCity = c.Account.BillingCity;
///same for rest of the fields

contactsToUpdate.add(c);
}

update contactsToUpdate;

}
```

It works fine.But my test class is giving me errors: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List at line 24 column 41

My Test Class

```
@isTest
public class UpdateContactBillingAddress_Test{
static testMethod void testupdates() {

// Let’s create our records from scratch!
Account a= new Account();
a.Name=’TestAccount';
a.BillingStreet=’hjasadhj';
insert a;
//update Account
a.billingState=’My City';
update a;

// Verify that the billingState field was updated in the database.
Account updatedAccount = [SELECT billingState FROM Account WHERE Id = :a.Id];
System.assertEquals(‘My City’, updatedAccount.billingState);

//Create record for new contact
Contact c=new Contact();
c.FirstName=’hina';
c.LastName=’meena';
List contact = [SELECT Id, MailingStreet,MailingCity FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :a.Id];
System.assertEquals(‘hjasadhj’, contact.MailingCity);

}
}
```

Can anyone help me find the error/debug it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is jus this line :

List contact = [SELECT Id, MailingStreet,MailingCity FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :a.Id];

make it

List< Contact > cnt = [SELECT Id, MailingStreet,MailingCity FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :a.Id];

it should work

Also in assert statement use contact[0].MailingCity instead of just contact.MailingCity

Comment: Its still giving Errors.

Comment: Error:Class name is already in use or has been previously used

Comment: Thats a different error. so your previous problem is solved. go to setup>> develop>> class , find your class , edit and save the code again.

Comment: Now the code is saved,but when I run it ,it fails                                            Error Message:System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0
Stack Trace:Class.UpdateContactBillingAddress.testupdates: line 23, column

Comment: Thats beacuse you have not inserted contact in the test class. just before you query just do : insert c

Comment: if you are jhappy with my answer and if it has resolved your problem, can you mark it as answer. It may help others. Thanks